# Is it possible to have a whisper function in a discord bot?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot that plays uno in the server the people are in. I was thinking about how I would go about it, until I realized I didn't have a way to represent what cards each person has. I then thought how I could say it to someone without telling it to the entire world that you had those certain cards... So is it possible to 'whisper' in discord, cus as a real person, I haven't seen someone do it and no one has ever done it to me.

Comment: You can send direct messages in discord. Bots are also capable of this

Comment: Sorry, but meant that if you typed in something int he chat, it will 'whisper' it to the people in the server. not DM's. inside the chat itself

Answer (score 1):

You can send a Direct Message to the user,

Suppose your players are player_a and player_b (discord.Member objects), the you can simply

```
player_a.send(cards_a)
player_b.send(cards_b)
```

Comment: sorry for the long wait, but I specifically don't want DM/PM's. Is it possible to do that in the server itself?

Comment: I suppose you could create a private channel just for the user and the bot + admins or whoever, but that would be too much of a hassle especially for big servers

Answer (score 1):

You can make bot send Direct Message to inform how many cards does the user have.
This command will show you how to do this. (made in rewrite version)

```
@bot.command()
async def cards(ctx):
user = ctx.author
await user.send("You have 20 cards!")
```

With this small command you are sending a Direct Message to a user who used this command.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way at present to send a message only to one person within the chat context on an unboosted server (a point seemingly lost upon other respondents to date).

You can send a direct message - but that's not in the chat context, and only works if they let the bot do so. In other words, unreliably for bots.

If user trust is high, you can use markdown to spoiler-text it; this keeps it in the chat context (no hopping between the chat and your DMs panes), but only as private as the trustworthiness of the participants.

There is one additional prospect: private threads. Threads are reasonable good in theory... but private threads are gated under Server Boost level 2. It's still a context-jump, but not as far, as threads appear in the channels, rather than as separate from the server, and, for those in the threads, in the parent chat.

I don't have access to a boosted server to test this.

In any case, if using such a boosted server, making a private thread between bot and user

**References**
https://www.markdownguide.org/tools/discord/
https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4403205878423-Threads-FAQ

Answer (score 0):

Try using interaction.send. Also a good place to check is the discord documentation ik that there is a way to do it with interactions and there is a specific thing you can do to make it only send to you while it is in the same channel. Also please provide what you have tried!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).